# Liberando acesso externo a determinada porta através de IPTables

Tags: linux, redes, firewall

Atualmente tenho duas placa de rede no meu servidor Ubuntu 16.04, configuradas da seguinte forma no arquivo *interfaces*:

```
auto lo eno1 enp2s0
iface lo inet loopback

#Rede Externa que vai para antena de Internet
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

#Rede interna
iface enp2s0 inet static 
address 192.168.20.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.20.0
broadcast 192.168.20.255
```

Preciso criar uma regra de firewall, que irá enviar pacote para o ip: ...100 pela porta 6515, através de um computador da minha rede interna (.20.239).

Ou seja:

**192.168.20.239:6515 -----> 192.168.20.1:6515 (IP Servidor) -----> 192.168.0.100:6515 (IP Antena)**

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estava testando o script abaixo, porém, consegui direcionar apenas minha internet para a rede interna:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          compartilhar
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start compartilhar at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by compartilhar.
### END INIT INFO

# Interface da Internet:
ifinternet="eno1"

# Interface da rede local
iflocal="enp2s0"

iniciar(){
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $ifinternet -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $iflocal -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6515 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP
}

parar(){
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
}

case "$1" in
"start") iniciar ;;
"stop") parar ;;
"restart") parar; iniciar ;;
*) echo "Use os parâmetros start ou stop"
esac
```

Segue topologia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde.

São duas regras que você vai precisar: uma de forward e outra de nat.

A regra resposável pelo Nat ficaria assim:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enp2s0 --dport 6515 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:6515
```

A regra para forward:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 6515 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Para funcionar o forward é necessário ativar o seu módulo com o seguinte comando:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

**Editado**

De acordo com os levantamentos, essa é a estrutura que eu imagino.

**OBS:** Estou assumindo que a sua rede 192.168.20.0/24 está em Nat, ou seja, abaixo do 192.168.0.100 e que não possui rotas de acesso à ela.

[image: Proposta da solução]

Como você deseja fazer um acesso de fora para dentro, será necessário acesso aos gateways da empresa. Em cada gateway será necessário adicionar um redirecionamento (redirect), bem como um acesso (input).

Minha dica é que você tente fazer esse redirecionamento primeiro na rede 192.168.0.0/24. Para isso, vai precisar adicionar essas regras apenas no seu Ubuntu (192.168.0.100). As máquinas dessa rede deverão enviar suas requisições ao IP 192.168.0.100, com destino à porta 6515 (ou outra de sua preferência). Essa por sua vez, fará o redirecionamento para o seu HardKey, sob a porta 6515.

Vamos às regras.

A regra de **input** no 192.168.0.100 você já tem no seu script, apenas adicionei a interface:

```
iptables -A -i eno1 INPUT -p tcp --dport 6515 -j ACCEPT
```

E a regra para o redirect (**--dport 6515** aqui você pode escolher outra porta caso necessário):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.100 --dport 6515 -j DNAT --to 192.168.20.239:6515
```

Comment: Neste caso, está sendo liberado o acesso de apenas envio? Para ativar o envio e recebimento para esta porta, teria que acrescentar o que?

Comment: Acredito que levei a questão para outro entendimento e não te respondi de acordo. A porta 6515 está em um dispositivo da rede 192.168.0.0/24 (ex: 192.168.0.50), correto? O IP 192.168.20.239 consegue pingar para esse destino?

Comment: Na realidade é o seguinte, no computador da rede local (192.168.20.0/24 -> 20.239) tenho uma HardKeyUSB que utiliza a porta 6515. Na minha rede local consigo acessar ela de outros computadores, mas a partir do servidor não consigo. Preciso acessar ela após o servidor também. Preciso disso, para minha antena de internet conseguir compartilhar ela com meu Ip Externo para acessar a HardKey de fora da empresa.

Comment: Editei de acordo com essa última colocação. Acredito que agora possa te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém ainda não consegui comunicar. Na topologia você tratou o Firewall como algo separado, porém, o Firewall se encontra dentro do servidor Ubuntu. Coloquei uma imagem da minha topologia.

Comment: Tuas regras estão ok. Acredito que falte apenas liberar o forward para que as duas interfaces se comuniquem. Adiciona essa linha: iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface enp2s0 -j ACCEPT